# How to prevent fear of fireworks in dogs?

Tags: dogs, fear, sound

Many dogs are afraid of the sound of fireworks. They panic, often barking and sometimes becoming aggressive. One could sedate the dog before July 4th, but that's not the best for the dog. What other options do I have?

Comment: If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very trained with dogs, but the internet has several seemingly good guides related to [dogs fireworks](//google.com/search?q=dogs+fireworks), of which two caugh my interest:

- [How to Keep Your Dog Safe an Calm During Fireworks](http://www.cesarsway.com/dogbehavior/hyperdog/How-to-Keep-Your-Dog-Safe-and-Calm-During-Fireworks) By Cesar Millan
- [10 Safety and Calming Tips for Dogs During Fireworks](https://positively.com/contributors/10-safety-and-calming-tips-for-dogs-during-fireworks/) by Lisa Spector

Some key element from these articles:

- If possible, desensitize the dog to the sounds. In advance play sounds of fireworks at an increasing sound volume before the dogs eats, walks, or other comfortable situations
- Prepare a safe and known place, either at a different location or in your own home. The more sound isolated the better. Make sure that the dog knows and is familiar with place prior to the 4th of July
- As the key point is to help the dog remain calm, make sure that the dog has known company during the fireworks, either by your self or a known sitter
- Having a good exercise/walk earlier on the day also seems to be a good idea

Have a good independence day!

Comment: These are good ideas, but I wanted to make clear that desensitizing a dog who is afraid of fireworks can take many weeks or months. There isn't time left for this year, so be sure to keep your dog safe.

Answer (score 0):

You should find a quiet room in your house which can be done with the following criteria:

- Make sure it has no windows.
- If not so then make sure the room has minimal windows with curtains.
- A door that closes properly.

Okay now that you have the ideal room you can begin sound proof the area. You can do this by:

- Having bookcases against the walls to absorb the sound.
- Hanging up blankets on the room with pillows on the sides to help keep them up and further help stop the sound.
- Getting biggest furniture and putting them across the walls.

Make sure you leave some water and food out for the dog so that they don't go hungry. In addition to this you should regularly check them just to be sure. If you have a fan you should put that on in the room since with  all the padding on the walls the dog will get very hot. You could put ear muffs on your dog's ears or ear plugs as well, and with all this sound prevention your dog should be just fine.

Have a good independence day!